# mysql - display the values that exists in ALL the tables

Tags: mysql

i did a quick search here but wasn't able to find the answer i was looking for. here is what i would like to do:

i am creating a simple event registration tracking system.

i have a database called registration and in that database i have created **10 tables** called table1, table2..... table10. all these tables just has **one column: user_id**

i have one more table called **userinfo** and this table has 2 columns called `user_id` and `username` .

i need to create a query that checks whether **ANY user_id exists** in ALL the tables. if it does, it will display that user's name from the userinfo table.

i was thinking of using count function to get the total count for each user_id and if i get a count of 11, it will tell me that **user_id** exists in every table.

but I am not sure if that the proper way to go. any ideas will be appreciated. i am not good with queries so if someone could post an example as well. thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I think you need to rethink your table layout, actually. What's the purpose of those tables? If they only differ by type, why not only have one table, where you link the UserID to the event type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do an inner join on all the tables on the `user_id` field, and display the username from userinfo table only if a result exists in the joined query :

```
SELECT username FROM userinfo it WHERE EXISTS (

SELECT user_id FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN Table2 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN Table3 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN Table4 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN Table5 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN Table6 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN Table7 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN Table8 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN Table9 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN Table10 USING(user_id)
WHERE t1.user_id = it.user_id
);
```

Comment: why not just join userinfo to the other tables?

Comment: @ysth it can work either of course. However I think that the shown way in the answer can be better understood by the OP, I think it is clearer.

Comment: one more question. lets say i get 5 results from the query above. if i wanted to only show 1 randomly selected row, how can i do that?

i tried adding: ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1 but i got an error. im not sure if i can use order by in that query.

other idea i has was to somehow export the results returned by above listed query and then import it into a separate table and run SELECT * FROM result_table ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1 and hopefully that will work.