# inner join - check if value exists in ALL tables

Tags: inner-join

i originally posted a question in this thread:
 [mysql - display the values that exists in ALL the tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463902/mysql-display-the-values-that-exists-in-all-the-tables)

And aleroot thankfully suggested a solution. i tried it and everything seemed to work. however, i have added more tables and for some reason it no longer works.

as a test, i imported same values in all 29 tables. however, when i run the query below, it doesn't return any rows. not sure what i am doing wrong. any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks

```
SELECT @rownum:=0;
SELECT name FROM userinformation ui  WHERE EXISTS (

SELECT user_id FROM userinformation t1 
INNER JOIN table1 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table2 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table3 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table4 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table5 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table6 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table7 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table8 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table9 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table10 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table11 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table12 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table13 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table14 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table15 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table16 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table17 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table18 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table19 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table20 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table21 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table22 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table23 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table24 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table25 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table26 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table27 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table28 USING(user_id)
INNER JOIN table29 USING(user_id)
WHERE t1.user_id = ui.user_id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, that when you use join, system has to fetch all the records, connect them together, and then apply the filter (WHERE clause). So, when you're trying to get data from 29 tables, you're actually trying to get 29*(cols_num) fields for each user_id, and there's a restriction depends on your database settings or realisation.

Try to use subqueries or exists directives, for example

```
SELECT user_id FROM userinformation t1 WHERE 
EXISTS (SELECT user_id FROM table_1 t WHERE t.user_id=t1.user_id) AND
EXISTS (SELECT user_id FROM table_2 t WHERE t.user_id=t1.user_id) AND
SO ON...
```